# In R, how can I construct an anonymous list containing an element whose name is contained in a variable?

Tags: r, indirection

I would like to insert an element into a list in R. The problem is that I would like it to have a name contained within a variable.

```
> list(c = 2)
$c
[1] 2
```

Makes sense. I obviously want a list item named 'c', containing 2.

```
> a <- "b"
> list(a = 1)
$a
[1] 1
```

Whoops. How do I tell R when i want it to treat a word as a variable, instead of as a name, when I am creating a list?

Some things I tried:

```
> list(eval(a)=2)
Error: unexpected '=' in "list(eval(a)="
> list(a, 2)
[[1]]
[1] "b"

[[2]]
[1] 2
> list(get(a) = 2)
Error: unexpected '=' in "list(get(a) ="
```

I know that if I already have a list() laying around, I could do this:

```
> ll<-list()
> ll[[a]]=456
> ll
$b
[1] 456
```

...But:

```
> list()[[a]]=789
Error in list()[[a]] = 789 : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

How can I construct an anonymous list containing an element whose name is contained in a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option:

```
a <- "b"
> setNames(list(2),a)
$b
[1] 2
```

or the somewhat more "natural":

```
l <- list(2)
names(l) <- a
```

and if you look at the code in `setNames` you'll see that these two methods are so identical that "the way to do this" in R really is basically to create the object, and then set the names, in two steps. `setNames` is just a convenient way to do that.

Comment: thanks! doing this via the setNames trick lets me do foo <- c(foo, setNames(list(baz),bar))